# Get presence/activity of mentioned user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command for my bot in Discord JS that when triggered, takes the command's mentioned user and retrieves their current game (If no game, then status) and sends a message saying **Mentioned user** has been playing **Game** for **Time elapsed** (And if possible, send the image of the game if it has one).

This is my current code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'game',
    aliases: ['gm', 'status'],
    category: 'Commands',
    utilisation: '{prefix}game',

    execute(client, message) {
        let msgMention = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.member(message.author)

        console.log(msgMention.presence.activities[0])

        message.channel.send(msgMention.presence.activities[0].name);
    },
};
```

All it does with the `.name` extension says name is undefined and if I remove `.name` it says cannot send an empty message. Also, I mention myself currently playing a game that so shown publicly on my discord activity status. What can I do so it actually reads the name and time of the activity to then send it?

Comment: What does `msgMention.presence.activities[0]` log?

Comment: undefined and nothing else

Answer (score 2):

You need the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES] });
```

Also btw I'd recommend using `message.member` instead of `message.guild.member(message.author)`

```js
let msgMention = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member
```

Comment: Should also probably add an optional chaining operator in the `members` property because it is not guaranteed to exist. So `message.mentions.members?.first()`.